# Concept of "Performance Counters" in Linux/Unix

Tags: windows, linux, unix, performancecounter

Windows has a [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx) infrastructure. The OS provides some common counters, and I can go add my own. What is the corresponding concept in Linux/Unix?

Comment: This question probably belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: Not for serverfault. I am looking for what kind of API support Linux/Unix have if I want to expose counters.

Comment: Oprofile should be the answer for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net)
- [perfctr](http://perfctr.sourceforge.net/)
- [perfmon2](http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: They all are for hardware counters (PMU unit of CPU, cycles, instructions, branches and misses, L1/L2 cache access/miss). There is also **newer `perf` tool** (perf_events, http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html, https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) to access hardware PMU, but it also support some predefined software events and can use many tracepoints.

Answer (score 3):

There is also PAPI and PerfSuite.

Answer (score 1):

Several applications exist which periodically check system performance.

- [iostat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat), [vmstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat), and [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) - Run these commands once to get a snapshot of activity.
- [sysstat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) - This runs periodically and maintains a history of statistics such as the above.
- [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) - As sysstat, but with pretty web graphs.