# Equivalent for Win32 performance counters on Linux

Tags: linux, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concept of “Performance Counters” in Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100733/concept-of-performance-counters-in-linux-unix)

What are the Linux equivalent of Windows's performance counters?

- API/libraries to publish application counters
- API/libraries to monitor and collect values efficiently (like pdh.dll)
- applications to monitor the current values (equivalent of perfmon.exe)
- applications to schedule collecting (like logman.exec)
- applications to visualize collected values (again, perfmon.exe)

Or, to put it more broadly, what is the recommended system performance monitoring infrastructure on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

There's one infrastructure with supporting tools that have been in the mainline kernel for along time, [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/). However, the interface was in some respects broken, and it didn't really see much use outside the somewhat primitive oprofile command line tools. Then there were a bunch of "oprofile replacements", perfmon, perfmon2, perfctr, perfmon3(?), etc., until finally a few months ago the [Perf events](http://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) infrastructure was merged.

Then there are a number of higher level libraries and tools built on top of the above kernel level interfaces, such as [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) and [TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs.php)